# Run a PHP Cron Job on macOS & MAMP

Tags: macos, cron, mamp

I'm trying to run a cron job on macOS and a site hosted locally using MAMP.

I have tried various options, none to any avail; please see below:

```
*/1 * * * * php http://mylocalsite.com/cron/my_function

*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/curl –silent –compressed http://mylocalsite.com/cron/my_function

*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/curl --silent --compressed http://mylocalsite.com/cron/my_function

*/1 * * * * /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.12/bin/php http://mylocalsite.com/cron/my_function > /dev/null 2>&1

*/1 * * * * wget --no-check-certificate -O- https://mylocalsite.com/cron/my_function >> /dev/null
```

When I run the following in terminal, it does work:

```
wget --no-check-certificate -O- https://mylocalsite.com/cron/my_function >> /dev/null
```

I know that the URL executes the function that I want as I have tested this directly in a browser.

What am I doing wrong and what should go into the crontab in order to ping/run the specified URL?

Comment: Would it also be an option to trigger the php script directly? Then */1 * * * * php /path/to/script.php on the server where you host the script should be sufficient.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using CodeIgniter so pinging a specific method via URL is the easiest (that I can think of).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CodeIgniter manual suggests that running CodeIgniter through the commandline is possible.

They write the following script:

```
<?php
class Tools extends CI_Controller {

        public function message($to = 'World')
        {
                echo "Hello {$to}!".PHP_EOL;
        }
}
```

In turn they execute the script like this on the server:

```
$ cd /path/to/project;
$ php index.php tools message
```

Where tools denotes the controller, and message the action.

So in that case the crontab entry would become:

```
*/1 * * * * cd /path/to/project; php index.php tools message
```

And in the case sketched in the question:

```
*/1 * * * * cd /path/to/project; php index.php cron my_function
```

SOURCE: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/cli.html

Answer (score 0):

The thing I like to do is:

1. Make sure you have php installed using brew (`brew install php@version` (I use php@7.4))
2. Check if you have crontab, else install using `brew install crontab`
3. Enter `crontab -l` into the terminal, this will open a vim editor. If you can't seem to type anything press the `i` key. Then start entering the commands like :
   `*/1 * * * * cd /path/to/project; php index.php`
4. press `:` and following it enter `wq` and enter to save and exit the vim, making it `:wq`
5. check cronjob using `crontab -e` in terminal

Additional details [here(for crontab)](https://medium.com/@jsstrn/scheduling-with-cron-c5e5191663c6) and [here(for vim)](https://www.keycdn.com/blog/vim-commands)